# In Power BI, is there a way to dynamically return a value in a column based on a calculated date?

Tags: powerbi

I have a column of dates and a column of values in Power BI.  I also have three measures that return the beginning of the month, quarter and year for the date column.  Is there a way to return the value from the value column using the three measures i have?

I thought the following DAX measure would get me there:

BeginningOfMonthValue =
Calculate(
SUM('Table'[Value]'),
FILTER(
'Table',
'Table'[Date] = [BeginningoftheMonthMeasure]
)
)